# Bootstrap 3 expand accordion from URL

Tags: javascript, hash, twitter-bootstrap-3, anchor, accordion

Using Bootstrap 3, I'm trying to use sub-navigation anchor links (ie, index.php#wnsh) to expand a specified accordion and anchor down the page to the content. I've tried searching for examples but with little luck, likely because my accordion structure is different from the given BS3 example. Here's my HTML:

**UPDATE:**

Made a few updates to the code, but it still isn't opening the accordion specified by the hash. Any further thoughts?

```
            <div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">                
                <div class="panel">
                    <h4 id="cs" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#cs_c">Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea</a></h4>
                    <div id="cs_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse in">
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="chgd" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#chgd_c">Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron</a></h4>
                    <div id="chgd_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="wmnh" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#wmnh_c">Women’s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification</a></h4>
                    <div id="wmnh_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
var elementIdToScroll =  window.location.hash;

if(window.location.hash != ''){
  $("#accordion .in").removeClass("in");
  $(elementIdToScroll).addClass("in");
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(elementIdToScroll).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing the [transition plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) because it works fine for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S39Q7/)

Comment: Transition plugin is there. I'm trying to open a specific accordion via url hashtag, something like page.html#cs. The actual accordion functionality works fine for me.

Comment: I think you can write javascript that runs on page ready. You can get the hashtag using `window.location.hash` and do something like I have done in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S39Q7/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pitamber-tiwari, I tried your code and although it works with the hash hardcoded, it didn't work with window.location.hash, nor was the first accordion open on page load.

Answer (score 20):

Tested and working in Bootstrap 3.3.5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(location.hash != null && location.hash != ""){
        $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
        $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same problem just few minutes ago. The solution appears to be straight forward - you need to parse an *URL* and add class `in` to the matchable accordion, using its *id*:

```
// Opening accordion based on URL
var url = document.location.toString();
if ( url.match('#') ) {
    $('#'+url.split('#')[1]).addClass('in');
}
```

Tested and working in Bootstrap 3.1.1.

Comment: That helps me, but i would add this:

var url = document.location.toString();
if ( url.match('#') ) {
    $('#'+url.split('#')[1]).collapse('show');
}

To get the javascript effect.

Comment: Any particular reason we aren't using `window.location.hash`?

Comment: @dumP What do you mean by "to get the javascript effect". What effect?

Comment: @dumP I edited the answer to include your bootstrap-way of doing this. (the preferred method IMO)

Comment: this works fine

Answer (score 6):

With **Bootstrap 4.4**, just adding this single line to my JS code (inside a document ready clause) seems to do the trick:

```
if(location.hash != null && location.hash != ""){$(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in Yii2 with the Collapse widget.
Assign an id to your panels.
If you have plain html you can just add an id to your a-tag and update the selector.

```
$(function(){
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        $(hash).find('a').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a response, to Ilia R's. His solution worked great! The only thing, though, was that the panel title style wasn't updating (the .collapsed class needed to be removed from the panel title link), so I tweaked Ilia R's code a tad. Someone probably has a better / cleaner solution, but here's a start.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var url = document.location.toString();
            if ( url.match('#') ) {
                $('#'+url.split('#')[1]).addClass('in');
                var cPanelBody = $('#'+url.split('#')[1]);
                var cPanelHeading = cPanelBody.prev();
                cPanelHeading.find( ".panel-title a" ).removeClass('collapsed');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = document.location.toString();
        if ( url.match('#') ) {
            var cPanelBody = $('#'+url.split('#')[1]);
            cPanelBody.find(".panel-title a")[0].click();
        }
    });
```