# Sourcecode works for chrome, not for Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm newbie in web development.

If I use the adress "www.xxxxxx.com/test.html#chgd", the second accordion should be expanding. It works perfectly for Chrome but not for Firefox and Explorer.

What is the problem in the source code that works for Chrome but not for Firefox and Explorer?

I have a similiar purpose ([Expand Specific Accordion from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987154/expand-specific-accordion-from-url/29987759#29987759)) but is it totally different problem statement.

I also have used 'window.location.hash;' but unfortunately, same problem occur.

[image]

[image]

```
        <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
        <script>

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var url = document.location.toString();
                if (url.match('#')) {
                    var hash = url.split('#')[1];

                    // collapse the expanded panel
                    $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

                    // expand the requested panel
                    $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">                
            <div class="panel">
                <h4 id="cs" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#cs_c">Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea</a></h4>
                <div id="cs_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse in">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>

                <h4 id="chgd" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#chgd_c">Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron</a></h4>
                <div id="chgd_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>

                <h4 id="wmnh" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#wmnh_c">Women’s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification</a></h4>
                <div id="wmnh_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand Specific Accordion from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987154/expand-specific-accordion-from-url) -> Same content, slightly different question...

Comment: In IE, have you checked what console would tell you? Press F12 the. Console.

Comment: Try `window.location.hash` to get the hash value.

Comment: Tim - I would like to say same purpose but not same question or problem statement.

Comment: your css & js files are localy? and site is on webserver?

Comment: Mark - every sourcecode is located in my local computer. i don't use a webserver.

Comment: MacKentoch - difficult to explain the content of the website in IE when I retrieve a error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the source code is

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  and not         <script src="C:\Users\h\Desktop\test\jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>   in relation to Firefox.
```

In IE, make sure that you have disactivate the activecontrol and everything will be alright.