# JQuery Accordian - Expand DIV within DIV with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have been beating my head with this one, and I have searched up and down stack overflow and elsewhere.  The closest answer I have found is [Expand Specific Accordion from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987154/expand-specific-accordion-from-url) but I cannot get it to work with my site.

I would like to enter a URL with an anchor like www.xyz.com/page#weather from another page/site and have it automatically go to and expand a li, which is inside of another li.  I have tried adding #abc to a href=#abc and then trying code similar to the included URL.  I have tried adding id's to the li that I need.  The code below is based on the live structure as it is right now.  I don't want to confuse myself and others by changing it up and making a mess when trying to get help.  I inherited this code, and overhauling right now it is not an option.

I appreciate any help you are able to provide.

The page structure is:

```
<ul data-ui="accordian">
  <li data-ui="expandable">
    <a href="#" class="Toggle">Main accordion title here</a>
    <div class="content">
      <ul data-ui="accordian">

        <li data-ui="expandable">
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Inner accordion title to expand</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>some text here</p>
          </div>
        </li>

        ...

        ...

      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the accordion script:

```
(function($) {

    $.Expandable = function(el, options) {

        /**
         * Default settings
         * @access private
         * @type {Object}
         */
        var defaults = {

        };

        /**
         * Current instance
         * @access private
         * @type {*}
         */
        var plugin = this;

        /**
         * Plugin settings, defaults merged with user options
         * @access public
         * @type {Object}
         */
        plugin.settings = {};

        /**
         * Reference to the jQuery version of the DOM element
         * @access private
         * @type {Object}
         */
        var $element = $(el);

        /**
         * Reference to the DOM element
         * @access private
         * @type {Object}
         */
        var element = el;

        /**
         * The control that toggles open/close state
         * @access private
         * @type {*}
         */
        var title = $element.find('>.toggle');

        /**
         * All pages
         * @access private
         * @type {*}
         */
        var content = $element.find('>.content');

        var siblings;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * @access public
         */
        plugin.init = function() {

            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            title.on('click', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                if($element.hasClass('open')) {
                    content.slideUp('fast');
                    $element.removeClass('open');
                    return;
                }

                content.slideDown('fast');
                $element.addClass('open');
            });

            if($element.hasClass('open')) {
                content.slideDown('fast');
            }
        };

        // Call constructor
        plugin.init();
    };


    // Add the plugin to the jQuery.fn object
    $.fn.Expandable = function(options) {
        // iterate through the DOM elements we are attaching the plugin to
        return this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            if(undefined == $this.data('Expandable')) {
                var plugin = new $.Expandable(this, options);
                $this.data('Expandable', plugin);
            }

            if(typeof options == 'string') {
                $this.data('Expandable')[options]();
            }

        });
    }

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-ui="expandable"]').Expandable();
});
```

Comment: And how exactly is an accordian expanded, it's not something that happens all by itself, there has to be code that actually creates an accordian ?

Comment: did you read the accepted answer from that other question? it shows what to do

Comment: Adeneo, there is a script for the accordion, which is working perfectly fine.  I will update my question to include that script as well.

Comment: Cruiser, I did read the accepted answer; however, I was unable to get it to work.  In that user's example, they are expanding a single accordion.  I need to expand an accordion within an accordion.  Do I need to modify the js to add the open class to the parent accordion and also the child accordion?  Or, if the child accordion expands, will that also expand the parent?  I am asking because I am not sure, and I have not found a solution that works in my case.

Comment: zJorge thank you for your help thus far. I experimented with it some but got caught up in meetings. Do add id=deep-link to the outer ul or inner? Also, the URL will need to open the inner li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with after testing different things I have come across.  It allows me to enter a URL in the following form, which will expand a specific accordion within a parent accordion:  example.com/page#abc&def

I added an element id to each parent accordion, and then an element id for each child accordion.  This allows me to specify which accordion to expand, either parent or child, and then scroll to the parent element.  This may not be the prettiest, but I am trying to learn.  I apologize for my ignorance.

```
// get URL
var url = document.location.toString();

// check for char in URL
if ( url.match('#')) {
    if (url.match('&')) {
        var main=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#')+1,url.lastIndexOf('&'));
        var sub=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('&')+1);
        $('#' + sub).addClass('open');
    } else {
        var main=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#')+1);
    }

    $('#' + main).addClass('open');

    // scroll to expanded main panel
    document.getElementById(main).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this recently.  Here is how I solved this:

[barentsre.com/line-of-business/#general-aviation](http://www.barentsre.com/line-of-business/#general-aviation?theme=hypnos-child)

And this is the piece of JavaScript you will need:

```
var active = 1;
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    console.log(hash);

    if (hash.length > 0) {
        var section = $("#deep-link").children("li" + hash);
        var thisPanel = section.children(".responsive-accordion-panel");
        if (section.length) {
            active = section.index();
        }
        thisPanel.addClass('active').slideDown();
    }
```

Just add `id=deep-link` to your UL element, then replace `.responsive-accordion-panel` and `'active'` using your own structure.